# How Do I Find Amazon Product Names with requests-html?

Tags: python, python-requests-html

I've been trying to code a program in python that can return a list of all the product names on the first page. I have a function that gets the URL based on what you want to search:

```
def get_url(search_term):
    template = 'https://www.amazon.com/s?k={}&ref=nb_sb_noss_1'
    search_term = search_term.replace(' ', '+')
    url = template.format(search_term)
    print(url)
    return URL
```

Then I pass the URL into another function and here is where I need help. Right now my function to retrieve the title and number of reviews is this:

```
def getInfo(url):
    r = HTMLSession().get(url)
    r.html.render()
    product = {
        'title': r.html.find('.a-size-medium' '.a-color-base' '.a-text-normal', first=True).text,
        'reviews': r.html.find('.a-size-base', first=True).text
    }
    print(product)
```

However, the `r.html.find` part isn't getting the info I need, it either returns `[]` or None if I add first=True. I've tried different ways like using the XPath and selector. None of those seemed to work. Can anyone help find a way to use `html.find` method to find all the product names and save them in `title` in the dictionary product?